# Swiper 9 Element with Angular 15

Tags: angular, typescript, swiper.js

I followed the official documentation on:
[swiperjs doc](https://swiperjs.com/element)

I created a method to configure and initialize the swiper only when I have to show images

this is the HTML:

```
 <swiper-container #swiperRef init="false">
      <swiper-slide *ngFor="let src of srcPhotos">
          <img [src]="src" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;">
      </swiper-slide>
    </swiper-container>
```

this is the ts:

```
_initSwiper() {
    const swiperEl: any = document.querySelector('swiper-container');

    const swiperParams = {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      breakpoints: {
        640: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        1024: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
        },
      },
      on: {
        init() {
          // ...
        },
      },
    };
    
    // now we need to assign all parameters to Swiper element
    Object.assign(swiperEl, swiperParams);

    // and now initialize it
      swiperEl.initialize();
```

the swiper is created and works correctly, but in the console, I always get this error:

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQKYd.png)

referring to this event:
`swiperEl.initialize();`

I can't figure out where the problem is.

I tried to initialize the swiper in various ways but the error that comes out is always the same

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular you can use ViewChild instead of querySelector. Add this to the top of your class:

```
@ViewChild('swiperRef', { static: true })
protected _swiperRef: ElementRef;
```

Then replace:

```
const swiperEl: any = document.querySelector('swiper-container');
```

with

```
const swiperEl = this._swiperRef.nativeElement;
```

Also don't forget to only run `_initSwiper()` after srcPhotos has values